Calculate offset in world-space, to have a defined offset in view space (after homogenous transformation)?
In graphics we generally have a world space that we map to the view space using our 4x4 View Matrix View. (Generally speaking this consists of a Camera matrix, followed by the Projection matrix, so View = Proj * Cam). So, say we have a 3D point pworld, after turning it into a homogenous coordinate, we can project this point to our view space: pview = View * pworld. Pretty standard so far.
Here is where things get interesting/tricky, depending on your mentality. I want to alter the original point pworld in such a way that it has a specified offset o, in the view space. Let’s call the altered point p’world. In formula:
View * p’world = View * (pworld + o’) = pview + o
So we set o' in such a way, that after applying our View matrix, we are left with offset o in the view space. But how do we calculate this o' (which is a 3-dimensional vector)?
I came quite far with taking the inverse of View and trying things like o' = inverse(View) * o, but the homogenous divide adds a non-linearity that I've not been able to solve yet.

Ok, so you can solve it in the following way. I'm still hoping there's a "nicer" way involving less operations, but this at least might give you some ideas. I'll clean up the answer a little further tomorrow morning.
point_world is pworld, view_matrix is View and view_offset is offset o. The result is the calculated o'.
fn calc_world_offset2(point_world: Vec3, view_matrix: Mat4, view_offset: Vec3) -> Vec3 {
    let point_world4 = Vec4::from((point_world, 1.0)); // Create homogenous Vec4(p, 1.0)
    let point_view = view_matrix * point_world4; 

    let view_offset4 = Vec4::from((view_offset, 0.0)); // Create homogenous Vec4(o, 0.0)
    let offset_temp = view_matrix.inverse() * (view_offset4 * point_view.w);
    let point_offsetted_world = point_world4 + offset_temp; // Calculate p'_world

    (point_offsetted_world / point_offsetted_world.w).truncate() - point_world
}

